# Java IF ELSE statements

Tags: java, resultset

Quick question. I got a code below, which checks with a database whether a given ID is available in the database, if so, it retrieves all attendance histories for the ID, otherwise if the ID didn't exist in the database it should display an error message. The code I got however, always says that the record has been attached, and then displays the error message as well regardless whether the ID exists or not. I think I probably have to change the order of the code or such? Could you please advise?

```
    JButton button = new JButton("Submit");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


        String studentID = textField.getText(); 

        try {

            Statement st = con.con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT StudentID, date FROM attendance WHERE StudentID ="+textField.getText());


            while ( rs.next() ) {
                String student = rs.getString("StudentID");
                String date = rs.getString("date");
                System.out.println(student+"");
                System.out.println(date);
            }

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmAttendanceHistory, "Attendance has been registered.");
            frmAttendanceHistory.setVisible(false);

            if (!rs.next()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmAttendanceHistory, "A record for the given Student ID doesn't exist");
            }

        } 


        catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmAttendanceHistory, "Attendance couldn't be registered. Please try again!");
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're repeatedly calling `rs.next()` until it returns false (as otherwise you'll never get out of the while loop) - then you're calling `rs.next()` again. Why would you expect it to return true then?

I suspect you want something like:

```
if (rs.next()) {
    String student = rs.getString("StudentID");
    String date = rs.getString("date");
    System.out.println(student+"");
    System.out.println(date);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmAttendanceHistory,
       "Attendance has been registered.");
    frmAttendanceHistory.setVisible(false);
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmAttendanceHistory,
        "A record for the given Student ID doesn't exist");
}
```

Comment: AARGH WHY DO I ALWAYS GET NINJA'D BY JON SKEET??? I had so many beautiful things to say...

Comment: @Jon Skeet, thanks for your advise. your code works, however it doesnt loop? as we got an if statement rather than a while statement. what if i have to records with the given ID? as i just tried it out, it only displayed the first record, even though i have 2 records for the given ID?

Comment: @PitaSivam: No, it doesn't loop. There didn't seem to be any point in looping, given that you're just printing to the console. If you *do* want to loop, you should probably just create a `List<Attendance>` or something like that - then after the loop you can check whether the list is empty.

Comment: could you please advise how to do it with the List<Attendance> ? I guess i need the loop, because the code needs to go through the database and pick out all records with the given ID, and once gone through, and there is no record, it should display error message. If a record is found, obviously, it shouldnt display the error message?

Comment: @PitaSivam: Well first you'd need an `Attendance` class to represent the date and student. Then you'd create an instance of `ArrayList<Attendance>`. Within the loop, you'd create an instance of `Attendance` and add it to the list. To be honest, if this is new territory for you then you should really take a step back and look at the *core* of Java (collections, creating your own classes) before you keep going with databases.

Comment: Okay, is there any easier way of this? i am new to Java. The code i got right now is simple and neat and works perfectly. Only problem is, as soon as ONE record is found, it stops and displays it. It doesnt really retrieve all records that are queried?

Comment: @PitaSivam: If you're new to Java then you shouldn't be writing database code. You should learn about Java so that you're able to actually *understand* your code. The approach I've suggested isn't *difficult*, but it does require you to have a little bit of Java under your belt.

Comment: I am working on a Project for University, and I got to go through this now. I would quite like to learn this anyway. I was thinking if there is a way to do a WHILE IF AND ELSE Statement for this scenario? What do you reckon? would that work as an alternative?

Comment: Is there anyway, i can express that rs.Count = 0 or something about the size of the resultset?

Comment: @PitaSivam: That's not how the learning process works... don't go for a quick fix that you don't necessarily understand; learn how to do it properly, from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for your help Jon. You have been very helpful. As for now, I have done it using a different way around it and it works with the while loop too :)

Comment: @JonSkeet - One more question. If I wanted to display the results in a different popup window with a text field where the results would be in, how would i approach this? any suggestions?

Comment: @PitaSivam: Yes - you would follow my previous suggestion, to collect a list of the results... then you'd be able to display them in a popup.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a second rs.next, which would go to a second record if there was one.  If there's only one (which is already consumed further up in your app), then it fails giving you a success followed by a failure.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ( rs.next() ) {
```

followed by

```
if (!rs.next()) {
```

Doesn't make any sense as the `if` will always execute.  Your loop will continue until `rs.next()` returns false.